# how to run a script when rebooting/shutting down

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04. I'd like to run a script when the computer is rebooted or shutting down. I was using the same script with Kubuntu 14.04, but now, with 18.04 I guess I need to handle it via systemd.
Here is what I've tried so far:
I've commented the content of the script to just `echo "called" > /home/backup` to ensure it has been called
Created the symlinks in `/etc/rc0.d` like this:
`root:/etc/rc0.d# ll | grep quick
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   22 čec  1 16:46 K99quick-backup -> ../init.d/quick-backup`
 I've tried K99 and K01 none of it works
I added this to the beggining of the script (was working fine in 14.04 without it though):

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          my-service-name
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     0 6
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: your description here
### END INIT INFO
```

I can run the script manually by invoking `/etc/rc0.d/K99quick-backup` and so I can run it by `/etc/init.d/quick-backup`

I tried it using systemd

```
root:/etc/systemd/system# cat /etc/systemd/system/qbackup.service 
[Unit]
Description=Quick backup of settings
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/root/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target
```

and then
`systemctl enable qbackup.service ; systemctl daemon-reload`

This is what I get after reboot:
`ystemctl status qbackup.service`

```
● qbackup.service - Quick backup of settings
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/qbackup.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Could anyone please help me? Or just suggest simple way how to execute single bash script automatically for runlevels 0 and 6
Thank you

Comment: Just in case, it has been fixed by this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051311/how-to-run-a-script-when-rebooting-shutting-down#comment1717312_1051311)